# Can I run a 64-bit OS on my Pentium 4 computer?

Tags: 64-bit

Late models of Pentium 4 can run 64-bit OS, as I understand.
How to detect compatibility of my Pentium 4 processor with 64-bit OS?

I have following output for **sudo lshw -C processor**

```
 *-cpu
   description: CPU
   product: Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 3.00GHz
   vendor: Intel Corp.
   physical id: 4
   bus info: cpu@0
   version: 15.3.4
   serial: 0000-0F34-0000-0000-0000-0000
   slot: J2E1
   size: 3GHz
   capacity: 3060MHz
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 200MHz
   capabilities: boot fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe constant_tsc pebs bts pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl cid xtpr
   configuration: id=1
 *-logicalcpu:0
      description: Logical CPU
      physical id: 1.1
      width: 32 bits
      capabilities: logical
 *-logicalcpu:1
      description: Logical CPU
      physical id: 1.2
      width: 32 bits
      capabilities: logical
```

Output for **cat /proc/cpuinfo**

```
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 15
model           : 3
model name      : Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 3.00GHz
stepping        : 4
microcode       : 0x17
cpu MHz         : 3000.141
cache size      : 1024 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 2
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 1
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fdiv_bug        : no
f00f_bug        : no
coma_bug        : no
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 5
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe constant_tsc pebs bts pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl cid xtpr
bugs            :
bogomips        : 6000.28
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 128
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 32 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 1
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 15
model           : 3
model name      : Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 3.00GHz
stepping        : 4
microcode       : 0x17
cpu MHz         : 3000.141
cache size      : 1024 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 2
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 1
apicid          : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fdiv_bug        : no
f00f_bug        : no
coma_bug        : no
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 5
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe constant_tsc pebs bts pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl cid xtpr
bugs            :
bogomips        : 6000.28
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 128
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 32 bits virtual
power management:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the output of this command shows `lm` then your CPU is 64 bit

```
 grep -o -w 'lm' /proc/cpuinfo | sort -u
```

so doing this on your above output tells me your CPU is not 64 bit

Answer (score 3):

Your processor appears to be [this Pentium 4](https://ark.intel.com/products/27497/Intel-Pentium-4-Processor-supporting-HT-Technology-3_00-GHz-1M-Cache-800-MHz-FSB) according to Intel's ARK.

[image: ark showing a 32-bit CPU]

If the ARK is to be believed (and this is your processor), your CPU will *not* support 64-bit Ubuntu. You will be required to install 32-bit Ubuntu.